# Ionic3 - ElementRef nativeElement.getElementsByClassName returns collection but it is inaccessible

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7KhEJ-OLH_I) about Ionic and directives and everything works fine except when I try to get the FAB element using ElementRef's nativeElement.getElementsByClassName, like this:

```
this.fab = this.element.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('fab')[0]
```

That returns `undefined`. The problem is when I remove the index and print the whole HTMLCollection using `console.log`, it shows me a complete list with all the FAB's inside the element.

Running

```
console.log(this.element.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('fab'),
        this.element.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('fab')[0]);
```

on `ngOnInit` gives the following result:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Every part of the code related to the problem is equal to the tutorial and it's a quite recent video...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason here is that those elements are not present while you asking for them with that line:

```
console.log(this.element.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('fab'),
        this.element.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('fab')[0]);
```

There is simple example which shows where problem can be:

```
    console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('fab'), document.getElementsByClassName('fab')[0]);

    const el1 = document.createElement('div');
    el1.setAttribute('class', 'fab');

    const el2 = document.createElement('div');
    el2.setAttribute('class', 'fab');

    setTimeout(() => {
        this.abc.nativeElement.appendChild(el1);
        this.abc.nativeElement.appendChild(el2);
    }, 2000);
```

Elements are added after 2 seconds and console log is same like yours, but when you click on `HTMLCollection` it will evaluate and shows you those elements - of course if you click after 2 seconds(when elements are present).

If those element are really present when you asking for them console log should look more like:

```
HTMLCollection(2) [div.fab, div.fab]
```

Also, note that this little **i** in Google Chrome console inform you that value is evaluted just now - at the moment when you click on it.

Comment: oooh I see. I noticed that little i, but didn't understand what it meant lol. I'll try getting those elements in a timeout or something to ensure the elements will be available and give some feedback. It's weird because in the tutorial the guy uses those values right away... Maybe because his test page is basically just plain text? While mine is already populated with other stuff, so it takes longer to load or something like that...

Comment: And that was it. A simple delay to get the element solved the problem. Thanks!